# using access sql to do INSERT INTO (aggregate function)

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert

here's my code:

```
insert into archive from temp where temp.field6>archive.field6
```

i would like to insert the entire row into a table `archive` from table `temp` where one field is greater than another.

what is wrong with my syntax? it is giving me `ERROR ON INSERT InTO`

edit:

here is what i have so far:

```
INSERT INTO archive
SELECT temp.*
FROM temp, archive
WHERE temp.field6>max(archive.field6);
```

im sorry i was completely wrong with the first query

please note the new MAX

i am getting an error because i cannot use the aggregate function here.

Comment: I am not even sure where to begin fixing that. You are missing a select (which needs to include the temp table and the archive table if you are going to have a comparison). Perhaps you can be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish and what you have already done to try and figure it out yourself.

Comment: @lamb ive updated thank yo ufor your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO archive
SELECT temp.*
FROM temp
WHERE temp.field6>(SELECT max(archive.field6) FROM archive);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) you need to use more comprehensive syntax with SELECT. For example:

```
INSERT INTO archive SELECT temp.* FROM temp, archive 
GROUP BY temp.field6 HAVING temp.field6 > max(archive.field6);
```

Comment: thank you ive done exactly that but it is asking me for the values for temp.fiel6 and the other one

Comment: @I__: Yup, updated answer, but I am not sure is this what you want. I assume that archive and temp have same schema. Otherwise you need to specify column list for insert list and select list.

Comment: thank you again,. your query did not work. it did append rows but way too many. i tink there is an error. yes both tables have the same schema